# How to test MissingParameterException in cakephp?

Tags: php, exception, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I have tried every other post that was posted in stackoverflow and I can't figure it out. So this means that I should ask.

```
    public function bootstrapRadioButtons(
    $name,
    $options,
    $value = '',
    $divClass = '',
    $label = array('class' => 'control-label')
) {
    if (!isset($name) || !isset($options)) {
        throw new MissingParameterException(__d('cockpit', 'Variable name must be set.'));
    } else {
```

Could someone write a test where this MissingParameterException is tested ? Is there a specilazed way to test this using cakephp ?

This is what I have so far:

```
    /**
 * @expectException App\Exception\MissingParameterException
 */
public function testNameAndOptionsAreEmpty()
{
    $this->CommonHelper->bootstrapRadioButtons('', '');
}
```

This is what I use in the class itself:

> use App\Exception\MissingParameterException;

And that's exactly where this MissingParameterException come from, but this test still returns error.

```
    /**
 * setUp method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $view = new View();
    $this->CommonHelper = new CommonHelper($view);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition to chekc that !isset($name) and !isset($options) is redundant, because $name and $options parameters are required for this function, and php will throw an exception before executing your code. If You want to check that thay are not empty use this code:

```
if (empty($name) || empty($options)) {
    throw new MissingParameterException('Variable name must be set.');
}
```

And in this case test will looks like:

```
/**
 * @expectedException \Full\Namespace\To\MissingParameterException
 */
public function testNameNadOptionsAreEmpty()
{
    $class = new \Your\Class();
    $class->bootstrapRadioButtons('', '');
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you have? 
First. Have you changed the code that checks $name and $option? Because in current implementation (!isset($name) || !isset($options)) wont work. As I wrote you need to change condition to (empty($name) || empty($options)).

And second. Try to use full class path with back slash in expectedException:  \App\Exception\MissingParameterException;

Comment: Yes, I have followed your advice and change it to empty($name) || empty($options), but I can't hit the right namespace :-/

Comment: Are you sure that this class exists? I mean MissingParameterException class.  Because I've created the same test case and it works for me https://gist.github.com/sauron07/967c7a2e1c9989caa31f6371bf7cad0c

Comment: No, it doesn't exists by default. We have created it. I have followed your second advice and it works now. Thanks once again.